# Apple rejected my app because of iPad, but my app is only for iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

My app is a streaming player that I pushed to AppStore Connect

In Xcode, I don't check iPad :
[image]

And Apple said :

[image]

I tried despite everything to run it on iPad Simulator on Mac, and I found no crash. The button player is OK, both on iOS 12 and 13

What's the solution ?

Comment: The message is clear, they didn't reject your app because it was crashing. They rejected because there is some play button inside your app that does nothing. When they clicked that button then nothing happens. And according to the guidelines there shouldn't be any non functional things in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building for iPhone is not meaning that it is **ONLY** for iPhone! iPad users still can download iPhone apps (except they need some especial feature of the phone like `CoreTelephony`) and Apple's testers always test apps on iPad. So try to fix the bug (that is probably not related to the device). The issue is that you **Play button** is not working, not the device.

Comment: Really? But I have already another app in appstore, and it is only for iPhone!
Look here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4v3E.png

Comment: That message shows nothing. iPad users can download iPhone apps with the little 2x zoom button ;)

Comment: okay thank you, I'll try to fix the play button, but it is working good in my simulator.
I click on play and it's playing, and click on pause and it's paused ...

Answer (score 0):

you are providing screenshot for iPad also in iTunes connect to make sure if your app is only iPhone then you must add a screenshot for iPhone no need to add a screenshot for iPad just leave them empty